# Email validation in SAS using regexp - not catching comma or several email adresses in one field

Tags: regex, perl, sas

I am using the following PERL regexp function in SAS to validate emails:

```
if prxmatch('/^[a-z0-9_\.\+-]+(\.[a-z0-9_\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]{2,}(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.([a-z]{2,8})/', email) = 1 then prx =1 ;
else prx = 0;
```

This works for most emails, but in these cases, the code fails to catch invalids:

some@email.com, (with a comma at the end)

some@email.com, someother@email.com (Two separate emails in one string variable, separated by comma)

some@email.com/someother@email.com (Two separate emails in one string variable, separated by /)

These are easy to detect by using index(epost,','), but I recon there must be a way to include these in the prxmatch function, but I cant find the sollution. The regexp function is something I found, not something I have written myself, and although I understand most of it, I cant find the correct syntax.

Tried something like @{1} to denote only one @ allowed, but cant fingure how to work it in. Also tried a $/ at the end, but this also didnt work.

Comment: Your regex validates _some_ email addresses. But it's not according to the RFC.

Comment: Could you explain what happened when you ended your regular expression with a `$`, beyond "didn't work"? What didn't work - did it still match those invalid examples, or did it fail to match some valid examples? What if instead of `email`, you make the second argument to the `prxmatch` function `trim(email)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is undoubtedly to anchor the pattern at the end with `$` in the same way as your `^` anchors the start

Just to be sure, this is what you should have. Please try it and explain what you mean by *doesn't work*. Is there any chance you're trying to match email strings with trailing whitespace or a newline, which the original pattern would ignore in the same way as it ignores spurious commas?

I've separated out the assignment of the pattern and used the `/x` modifier so that insignificant whitespace can be added to the pattern to separate its elements and make it more readable

```
pattern = '/ ^ [a-z0-9_\.\+-]+ ( \. [a-z0-9_\+-]+ )* @ [a-z0-9-]{2,} ( \. [a-z0-9-]+ )* \. [a-z]{2,8} $ /x';
if prxmatch(pattern, email) = 1 then prx = 1;
else prx = 0;
```

Comment: SAS doesn't have VARCHAR concept, unfortunately, so in SAS $ is very easy to misuse.

Comment: It was my understanding that you do not have to escape special characters inside a class grouping.  This should be fine: `[a-z0-9_.+-]` Or am I wrong about that?  Are not all characters inside the brackets treated as literal except for the caret at the beginning?

Comment: @Squashman: I don't know about "should be".; it works perfectly well as it is. I simply copied the OP's pattern so as to avoid confusing things by changing more than necessary. Note that backslashes and hyphens that aren't at the beginning or end of the character class ***do*** need escaping

Comment: One more question.  What is the **x** doing at the end of the regular expression?  Was reading [this](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003288497.htm)  but could not determine what is was doing. Thanks

Comment: @Squashman: It's documented under **Flag Options** on a [different page](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp#TOC-Flag-Options). They're more often called *modifiers*.

Comment: Thanks @Borodin, just wanted to make sure I was covering all my bases before I post my own question.  I am using a slightly different regular expression that is approved by the client who is providing the data but I can't get it to work.  We are moving it from an AWK script that ran on Unix to a SAS program on z/OS.  I have used PXPARSE and PRXMATCH successfully in SAS in the past but not sure why I can't get this one to work. Probably post my question on Monday.  Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use modules from the cpan, I recommend `Email::Valid` to validate your email address instead of a regexp. Here is a sample:

```
use Email::Valid;

my @data = qw|some@email.com, some@email.com,someother@email.com some@email.com/someother@email.com|;

foreach my $addy (@data) {
   if (Email::Valid->address($addy)) {
        print "Valid Email $addy\n";
   } else {
        print "Invalid email $addy\n";
   }
}
__DATA___
Invalid email some@email.com,
Invalid email some@email.com,someother@email.com
Invalid email some@email.com/someother@email.com
```

Answer (score 0):

`$` can be tricky in SAS, because *every* SAS string has space padding unless it happens to be the exact maximum length of the field (which is rare or never in cases like this, if you set your length right).

As such, you need to either:

1. Trim your string before passing it to prxmatch (using `trim`, `strip`, or similar)
2. Tell your regexp that any number of spaces is allowed before the `$`.

I prefer 1:

```
prx_matched = prxmatch(pattern,trim(email));
```

But 2 is also fine, particularly if you need speed:

```
if prxmatch('/^[a-z0-9_\.\+-]+(\.[a-z0-9_\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]{2,}(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.([a-z]{2,8})\s*$/', email) = 1 then prx =1 ;
else prx = 0;
```

`\s` is the space metacharacter, and matches things other than space; however, it should be safe for email validation if you're properly dealing with your input.

---

In addition to the above, you need to add the `o` modifier to your regexp (and possibly `i`).  `o` prevents SAS from recompiling that static regexp every data step loop (which is very expensive).  `i` means `case insensitive` which you probably should be using also (unless you're really very sure you never have Capital Letters in your emails).