# SAS: Remove and replace specific character in string

Tags: sas

On this requirements so i need to add new logic on 'email_address' field.
that has 4 requirements.

1. not containts any blank space
2. if the value has '@' and '.' are not allowerd as the first and last character
3. Should be containts '@' and only allow 1 '@'
4. Character on email address should be'.' not be '..'

and all the email_address has following the four list above, must include on report exception.

Comment: What do you want to to here? Check if the E-Mail is valid or replace blanks with nothing and so on?

Comment: There are some anwsers to validate email address: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655679/email-validation-in-sas-using-regexp-not-catching-comma-or-several-email-adres

Answer (score 0):

There are far better rules for asserting a plaussbile email.

For the rules in the question at hand, you can try:

```
data have;
  length id 8 email $100;
  id = 1; email='@123'; output;
  id = 2; email='.jones@smith.co'; output;
  id = 3; email='a@b.c' ; output;
  id = 4; email='we.buy......gold@cha.ins'; output;
  id = 5; email='-@.-'; output;
  id = 6; email='    clams@bobs.shack'; output;
  id = 7; email='.-.@-.-.'; output;
  id = 8; email='dinner@7@dining.com'; output;
  id = 9; email='I''ll send you a fax'; output;
  id = 10;email='i-love-my-job..jk@drudgery.com'; output;

proc print data=have;
  where prxmatch ('/^[@.]|[@.]$/', trim(email))
     or countc(email,'@') ne 1
     or find(trim(email),' ', -32767)
     or index(email,'..')
  ;
;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I put all the rules in a regex.

```
proc print data=have;
  where prxmatch ('/^[@.]|[@.]$|@.*@|[ ]+|\.\./', trim(email))
  ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to save the result into a dataset, you can use `where also` statement, it means all where conditions take effects.

```
data want;
  set have;
  where also anyspace(trim(email))=0;
  where also email not in: ('@','.') and char(email,length(email)) not in ('@','.');
  where also count(email,'@')=1;
  where also find(email,'..')=0;
run;
```

Using `where also` statement make program easy to understand and easy to comment or uncomment where there are multiple conditions.